# Rspec. Multipart Recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec

I want to test my Mailer model.
Letters should be sent to multiple recipients.
How to test that messages sent to multiple recipients?
I created spec file:

```
describe SubscribeMailer do
  before(:each) do
   (1..3).to_a.each do  
    FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber)
   end  
  end

let(:post) { @user.posts.create(@attr)}
let(:mail) { SubscribeMailer.new_post(post) }

   #Failure/Error for this test
  it 'subscribers' do
    mail.to.should == Subscriber.all.map(&:email)
  end

end
```

But I don't know how to write the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test environment, ActionMailer.deliveries is an array of mail objects that would otherwise have been sent.

Comment: @apneadiving Too factual? God forbid! :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Trevoke answer, I'd tell you to have a look at [this excellent Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test).